# Can we use random forest where rows have a few columns as duplicates

Tags: r, random-forest

I have a historical dataset to study the behavior of accounts that have lapsed in previous quarter(s). There might be instances where one account ID might be lapsed 2 or 3 times and the account ID would repeat itself that many times.

Q1> Can I run RF for this training set? Account ID 57 is repeating twice but has different metadata if we look at other columns

excerpt:

```
AccountID   LOB     Country Region  Rev_before_lapse      Units   LapseQtr  LAPSE_FLG
57          ESG     US      AMER    34327.060             345     2016-Q2    Y
57          ESG     US      AMER    406364.290            640     2015-Q3    Y
15          ESG     US      AMER    345665.0              182     2014-Q3    Y
54          ESG     US      AMER    45674.9               765     2016-Q4    Y
52          ESG     US      AMER    UNK                   UNK     UNK        N
59          ESG     US      AMER    6366.660              11      2015-Q3    N
```

Q2> Also, I am facing problems with the LAPSE_FLG. This is what I would want to predict for 2017-Q2. Can I provide the value of LapseQtr = 2017-Q2 as an input in RandomForest function in R? If yes, please let me know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes  it is fine to run RF having two set of variables for the same ID, as your   LapseQtr are showing different point in time. You although need to include this variable as your predictor variable.. this is often seen in cases where you convert your data from wide to long format.

For your second question:you do not have values for other predictors of Q2- 2017... so i think you might have to think of creating new predictors, such as if it's q1, q2, q3, or q4... or number of years from your base year... i.e given your base year is 2012, 2015 will be three years from you best year... you need to do some feature engineering here I believe based on your context.